# Duplicate automations from one Business Unit to others

Tags: marketing-cloud, automation, sfmc-business-unit

After creating an automation (Data extract + File transfer) in Business Unit A, I would like to duplicate it to other Business Units. Is this possible ? If yes can you explain me how please ?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Have you looked at package manager for this use case?

Answer (score 1):

[Package manager](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.mc_overview_marketing_cloud_package_manager.htm&type=5) should be able to assist here